# add method to class subclassed from NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to ad a methode to an object (subclassed from NSManagedObject)

```
@interface REMBox : NSManagedObject {
}
- (int)singleValueForIndex:(int)index;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
```

but that methode can't be used

```
REMBox *box = ....
BOOL canCallMessage = [box respondsToSelector:@selector(singleValueForIndex:)];
// canCallMessage is NO
int a = [box singleValueForIndex:4];
// that crashes :-(
```

what's my fault. The normal (core-data) attributes of REMBox work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set the new subclass REMBox as class to be used for your entity in your datamodel?

Class "Event" for entity "Event" in this sample. Never forget to make a clean rebuild (sometimes even reopen your xcode project) if core data does unexpected things.

[image: CoreData entity class]

Comment: Martin, thank you. That was the essential hint I missed. The class in the datamodel was still NSManagedObject